# Table content is overflowing the division

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table with 2 rows but content is overflowing, as you can see in  [my codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwoXpm).

FYI Overflow is only for small screens, You can check by reducing screen size or developer mode of browsers.

I tried max-width, word-overflow neither worked could you help me out with this one. probably easy one but makes me go crazy....

thanks for help!

code:

```html
    <div class="bcontent" style="background-color:#F77B72;">
    <h2 style="color:#FFF; text-align:center;">GET IN TOUCH WITH US</h2>
    <hr style="width:10%; height:2px; color:#fff;background-color:#fff;" />
        <div class="container">
    <h4 style="color:#FFF; line-height:180%; text-align:center;">
    <table width="100%" align="middle">
      <tr>
     <td>ABCD abcdssd</td>
     <td>
    <a style="color:#fff;"href="mailto:rkthemes.social@gmail.com"> abcdefghijk@gmail.com            
    </a>
     </td>
     <td>XYZ abcdssd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>+91-9876543210</td>
     <td><a href="#" id="fb">
     <svg version="1.1" id="Icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         fill="#fff" width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
     <path id="Facebook" d="M38.078,22.431c0,2.268,0,12.391,0,12.391H29v15.152h9.078V95h18.649V49.975h12.513
         c0,0,1.172-7.265,1.74-15.209c-1.629,0-14.183,0-14.183,0s0-8.815,0-10.36c0-1.548,2.033-3.631,4.043-3.631c2.006,0,6.239,0,10.16,0
         c0-2.063,0-9.191,0-15.774c-5.235,0-11.189,0-13.814,0C37.617,5,38.078,20.167,38.078,22.431z"/>
     </svg>
     </a>
     <a href="#" id="tw" >
     <svg version="1.1" id="Icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     fill="#fff" width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100; color:#fff;" xml:space="preserve">
     <path id="Twitter__x28_alt_x29_" d="M84.803,46.564c5.055-0.417,8.483-2.715,9.803-5.833c-1.824,1.12-7.484,2.341-10.61,1.178
     c-0.153-0.734-0.324-1.432-0.492-2.062c-2.382-8.746-10.537-15.792-19.082-14.941c0.691-0.279,1.392-0.539,2.092-0.772
     c0.94-0.337,6.459-1.235,5.59-3.183c-0.733-1.713-7.475,1.295-8.744,1.688c1.675-0.63,4.447-1.714,4.743-3.64
     c-2.567,0.352-5.087,1.566-7.034,3.331c0.703-0.757,1.236-1.679,1.349-2.672C55.57,24.033,51.57,32.853,48.333,41.408
     c-2.542-2.463-4.795-4.403-6.816-5.48c-5.67-3.041-12.449-6.213-23.091-10.164c-0.327,3.521,1.741,8.203,7.7,11.316
     c-1.291-0.173-3.652,0.213-5.54,0.665c0.769,4.034,3.28,7.357,10.079,8.964c-3.107,0.205-4.713,0.912-6.168,2.436
     c1.415,2.805,4.868,6.107,11.08,5.429c-6.906,2.977-2.816,8.49,2.804,7.667C28.794,72.143,13.679,71.416,5,63.134
     c22.661,30.879,71.921,18.262,79.262-11.481c5.499,0.047,8.733-1.905,10.738-4.057C91.831,48.134,87.239,47.578,84.803,46.564z"/>
     </svg>
        </a>
     <a href="#" id="yo">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    fill="#fff" width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="YouTube__x28_alt_x29_" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;" d="M95,32.458C95,25.025,88.979,19,81.55,19h-63.1
        C11.021,19,5,25.025,5,32.458v36.084C5,75.975,11.021,82,18.45,82h63.1C88.979,82,95,75.975,95,68.542V32.458z M41,65.724V31.83
         l25.702,16.947L41,65.724z"/>
  </svg>
  </a>
  </td>
  <td>+91-9876543210</td>
  </tr>
</table>
      
   </h4>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried this on iPhone and cannot see any kind of overflow issue. Can you describe what the desired behavior is?

Comment: For screen width like 320px the content of table goes beyond container.

Comment: I don't think you should worry too much about such small resolutions, as nearly no phone has that low anymore. Anyway, you're having this issue due to the fact that the content doesn't fit inside the table. You need to make it fit somehow. Any desired behavior to achieve this?

Comment: nope.. just wanted make it work for all resolutions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `media queries` to achieve your desired result. Try adding something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    td {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
}
```

This will change the `font-size` of your `td` elements to a smaller font so that all content fits inside the table.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3kgobynx/)